# Build a doubly linked list in order without accepting duplicates

Tags: c++

This function works fine to create a doubly linked list of strings in order. However as written, it accepts duplicates.  I'm struggling with how to prevent that I thought it would be easy, I've commented out the code that I thought would work, but it definitely doesn't! It crashes with an exception that curr->next->data is a nullptr.  I don't see how that happens or more importantly how to simply refuse to accept a duplicate.  BTW, this is not a homework assignment, I was helping a student in a tutoring session.  His spec accepted duplicates.  I thought I could just enhance it for the fun of it to not accept dupes.

```
void sortedInsert(struct Node** head_ref, struct Node* newNode)
{
    struct Node* current;

    // if list is empty
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
        *head_ref = newNode;

    // if the node is to be inserted at the beginning
    // of the doubly linked list
    else if ((*head_ref)->data > newNode->data) {
        newNode->next = *head_ref;
        newNode->next->prev = newNode;
        *head_ref = newNode;
    }
    else {
        current = *head_ref;

        // locate the node after which the new node
        // is to be inserted
        while (current->next != NULL &&
            current->next->data < newNode->data)
            current = current->next;
       // if(current->next->data == newNode->data) check fotr dupe
        //{   
            /* Make the appropriate links */
            newNode->next = current->next;

            // if the new node is not inserted
            // at the end of the list
            if (current->next != NULL)
                newNode->next->prev = newNode;

            current->next = newNode;
            newNode->prev = current;
        //}  end if
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate values are the least of the multiple problems here. The first `else` clause's logic is wrong. If you use a debugger to inspect the values of all next/prev pointers, at that point, in the entire list, the linkage issue should be obvious. The entire doubly-linked list is corrupted.

Comment: You've been told before about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Voting to close.